# Gulp and Webpack does not show any info on console

Tags: gulp, webpack, workflow, frontend

I have a little trouble with my Gulp project.
Recently gulp sttoped to show practically any info about the buiding process(exept Browsersync messages). It looks like this now: [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQY0w.png)

I recently succesfully added Webpack to my project for processing Javasript, but it too works without any info.

I want it to look like this, as it were earlier: [Good one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVIWX.png)

My system and soft info:

- Windows 10 x64
- Node v6.9.3
- NPM 4.0.5
- Gulp 3.9.1

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long debugging i found, that **Gulplog Plugin** caused problems. After deleting it all things starts working